# No Python module named 'sp_api'

Tags: python, php, amazon-selling-partner-api

When I run the Python script via the PHP script it displays the following message:
**Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ETC./amazon_api.py", line 12, in from sp_api.api import MerchantFulfillment ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sp_api'**

When I run the Python script directly it works. It also works from the PHP script if the **sp_api.api** import line is commented out.

What's the problem?

```
<?php
$path = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ETC./';
$python_exec = "/bin/python3 {$path}amazon_api.py 2>&1";
echo shell_exec($python_exec);
```

```
# script: amazon_api.py
import sys
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

# $ pip show python-amazon-sp-api
sys.path.append('/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

from sp_api.api import MerchantFulfillment

print('OK')
```

When I list dir contents (~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ la -l) the package does exist:

...
sp_api
...

Comment: The user that the web server is running as probably can't access files under `/home/david/` so it can't load the library from there. You might try using a virtual environment or installing the packages in a location that the web server can read from, such as `/opt/lampp/.local/`.